# Derby's subquery optimization issue

Tags: derby, sql-execution-plan, optimization

here is to follow my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960344/apache-derby-hangs-up-executing-query) on Derby. I finally got it to show me the execution plan for my query and intresting values came up:
http://pastebin.com/wQAicPAV (SO parser goes crazy so i need to use external storage)

As you can see, some optimizer costs are INCREDIBLY BIG, and estimate row count too.
 optimizer estimated row count:    333734973.00
                        optimizer estimated cost:    205150563.85
Completely wrong values. And the query takes 22 minutes to execute.

I've seen this issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-1905

Which shows that most of the time optimizer is just trying to find the best plan for this query, and execution itself lasts significantly less.

So my question is - how to avoid this situation? Configure derby may be? Optimizer hints? Set timeout for that greedy basterd optimizer? I cant find anything about it in reference and i have no experience with derby at all.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather you can only avoid this by rewriting the query since the optimizer is "behaving badly" with this sort of query - sometimes it helps to use JOINs and or create views from some parts the query and use those in the query.

[Some general performance advice](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/tuning/index.html) (not sure you already tried that):

- [ensure current statistics](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/tuning/ctunperfstatistics.html)
- [Increase the size of the data page cache](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/tuning/ctunperf54492.html)
- [use in-memory-DB](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/tuning/ctunperfinmemdb.html)